# Google Talk Not Working

Tags: google-talk

I'm running on Ubuntu 13.10, and using Google Chrome 64 bit. Because Google Talk wouldn't work, I uninstalled the Talk Plugin to see if that changed anything, but no cigar. Here's an image that'll give you a better idea than I would.

[image]

On Chromium it worked perfectly, but not on Chrome itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same problem. After some fiddling around, now I seem to have reached an even worse situation where after every few seconds I get asked to install the Hangouts plugin. I've done this repeatedly but to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, it really stinks. I don't get the repeated request, but it is annoying. I think the next Ubuntu update will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should now be fixed. I checked in **about:plugins** in Firefox. The google-talkplugin was disabled for some reason. I went to plugins and set this to "Always Activate", now Google talk works properly.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed yesterday. Thanks! That tip is also helpful.